# How do the weights work for differents sets?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, neural-network

I'm reading about neural networks and cannot understand the point - how can it work if the weights are just updated to fit specific input-output pair?
I mean, the weights can be entirely different for another set. It will be adjusted for a specific case but will need to readjust based on output comparison for another case.
I just cannot see the "magic"..a simple example with input would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One example that is easy to undestand is simple [Curve Fitting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve_fitting) (take a look at the animation on this wikipedia page). This is a task that can also be done with a neural network. The "magic" is, that your network models a **function** which is approximated regarding your training data (the input-output pairs). New cases which have not been seen during training can be visualized as points between your training data points.

Now try to imagine the more general case, where you do not only have 1 input and 1 output value, but both multivariate. For example, take the 28x28 = 784 pixels of the [MNIST handwritten digits dataset](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/) with the 10 output neurons. Each output neuron models the probabilities that a given example belongs to each digit 0..9. During training, your network will learn **features**. This means it detects correlations in your input data which can thus be abstracted (you can also imagine this as a kind of "compression" sometimes). Thus, each of your neurons in the first hidden layer models one specific feature. You can visualize these features by considering the weights of one of the first hidden neurons as a grayscale image and paint it using an arbitrary imaging library like matplotlib for python. Try to train a neural network on the mnist database linked above and have a look at these features, this should clarify how this works.

The deeper hidden layers of your neural network now take the activations of the previous layers and learn *higher-level* features. This means they are combining the features of the previous layer to get an even more abstract representation of the input. This goes on for each following layer until you end up with 10 output neurons modelling the abstract information "There is a zero visible on the given input image".

Obviously, if you have enough training data covering many cases, you will end up with a lot of features. These features will work even when the given input differs from the cases you have used during training (e.g. a new zero which is slightly distorted).

Naturally, the *generalization performance* of your network depends on how many different general cases your training data cover. But there are also other factors regarding the architecture of your neural network which affect generalization performance. To mention some keywords, you should have a look at L1 and L2 regularization, weight decay, convolutional neural networks, dropout, etc. - all of them are techniques to further improve generalization performance.